# How can I import Excel data into an existing table in SQL Server and keep primary key incrementing accordingly

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I am using the SQL Server Import and Export wizard to import data from an Excel sheet into an existing table in my database. I want to append the data to the existing data, however I am stuck on figuring out how to keep the primary key in this table incrementing with the data I import. I don't have the `[ID]` column in my Excel sheet. The last value in my `[ID]` column is 105, so I would like for it to continue from there once I import.

Is there any way to do this through the wizard? I've tried the "Enable Identity Insert" check box in the column mappings window, however I still receive an error that I can not insert null values

Comment: If the column is an identity, you should *not* check "enable identity insert", and not map the ID column either -- the insert should then use the identity to generate the values. If the column isn't an identity, things get more complicated -- you'll have to either artificially add the column to Excel (and use auto-fill to quickly supply the values) or import things to an intermediate table and then write a query for the actual insert.

Comment: is the ID columns of your existing data an identity Field ? On which column do you get the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be simple. Alter your **ID** column as `identity` column increment by 1 and while importing data from your excel, don't map or do anything to this column. Just import all other columns without `Enabling Identity Insert check box`

Answer (score 1):

On which column is the NULL error? If it's the ID column, you should just ignore it as long as it's an identity column when the rest of the data is imported it should automatically increment. If not you can undo and CHECKIDENT to change the ID it'll start at.